# How do I scrape the last 10 Keno draws from the Georgia lottery into R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Web-scraping newbie - I'm trying to pull the last 10 draws of a Keno lottery game into R.  I've read several tutorials on how to scrape websites using the rvest package, Chrome's Inspect Element, and CSS or XPath, but I'm likely stuck because the table I seek is dynamically generated using Javascript.

I started with:

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
Kenopage <- "https://www.galottery.com/en-us/games/draw-games/keno.html#tab-winningNumbers"
Keno <- Read.hmtl(Kenopage)
```

From there, I've been unable to progress, despite hours spend on combinations of CSS and XPath calls with "html_notes."

```
#Failed example: 
DrawNumber <- Keno %>% rvest::html_nodes("body") %>% xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class,'Draw Number')]") %>% rvest::html_text()
```

Someone mentioned using the V8 package in R, but it's new to me.
How do I get started?

Comment: I simply tried `readLines(Kenopage)` and got the error HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'.  I think that they must not allow programmatic access to the page.

Comment: From one of the other tutorials, I learned about and used "Robotstxt" which claims to answer the question about programmatic permission.  This URL returned TRUE:    o install.packages(robotstxt)
o library(robotstxt)
o paths_allowed(
  paths = c("https://www.galottery.com/en-us/games/draw-games/keno.html#tab-winningNumbers")
)
o Look for "TRUE"